# how to solve Interface not visible from class loader in keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

Getting groups from keycloak using keycloak admin client dependency, which is properly configured in `module.xml`. But getting error such as

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource is not visible from class loader

I am working on event listener sysout project

```
Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance("http://localhost:8080/auth", "nodesjs-example", "admin-cli", token);
            List<GroupRepresentation> groupRepresentation2= keycloak.realm("nodejs-example").groups().groups();
            System.out.println(groupRepresentation2);
```

[image]

Comment: What is your keycloak-admin-client version , it should be same as your Keycloak server version

Comment: @ravthiru yes it is same both version are 5.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i got what you are doing. No need of admin Client, you can get from KeycloakSession (available in `EventListenerProviderFactory` create)

```
@Override
    public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return new SysoutEventListenerProvider(excludedEvents, excludedAdminOperations,session);
    }
```

Then in your EventListenerProvider you can get groups.

```
RealmModel realm = session.getContext().getRealm();
 List<GroupModel> groups = realm.getGroups();
```